# Protractor timeout with long running $http asynchronous tasks

Tags: angularjs, protractor

My e2e tests are failing because of timeout with long running $http requests. the following error is getting:
The following tasks were pending:
- $http: .....
 ScriptTimeoutError: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 10 seconds.

I have used $interval service to make http calls in my angular code to work with this kind of issues as per **https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/169**

But still protractor is failing with above error.
I am using angular 1.6.x and protractor 5.x.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: My angular application using event-streams and the http requetss never get closed so protractor is getting timeout. I used $interval to wrap my long running http requests but still protractor gettting timeout for long running tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Protractor not to wait for Angular $http and $timeout, like this way:

**Old deprecated way:**

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

**New correct way:**

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

Comment: If browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; is used then protractor will NEVER wait for $timeout or $http to finish before fulfilling, which can make tests flaky.

Comment: But he can set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;` after $timeout or $http section in his tests.

Comment: the problem is such event-stream (long running) http requests are using for all the views so everytime i make browser.ignoreSynchronization = false i get same timeout again. So i want to make my protractor to ignore such long running http requests.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message it looks like Protractor is waiting the default timeout of 11 seconds for Angular to be done. You can change this by increasing the `allScriptsTimeout`, see [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L380).

Have you tried that already?

**Update:**

I've been looking into the polling and interval stuff, maybe this link on [protractor git](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3349) helps. Have you also read [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#angular)?

Comment: Yes, i tried to set to 300 seconds maximum wait. but still it gets timeout because some asnyc $http requests taking longer time ex. i have used event-streams so the $http reqeusts never gets closed and protractor waits and gets timedout.